# Need to select average age of employees department wise

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, average

I have a table in Postgresql DB. It has 3 fields: Emp_Name, Dept & Age. I need to show Average age of employees department wise. I need to display all 3 fields in the result-set. Below is the input and expected output:

[image]

Here is the SQL Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7c4cf

How do I show the expected result in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `string_agg` function to concatinate the employee names and `avg` to get the average age:

```
SELECT   STRING_AGG(emp_name, ','), dept, AVG(age)
FROM     test1
GROUP BY dept
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7c4cf/2/0)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by on Dept and use `avg` and `string_agg` aggregate functions to get the desired result:

```
select
    string_agg(Emp_Name, ',') Emp_Name,
    Dept,
    avg(Age) Average_age
from test1
group by Dept;
```